# Attaching a user created recording to a form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure there is a super easy way to do this, but I'm pretty new to web programming so not sure of how to actually do it. I have a simple form that takes in a doc file and a media file (the media file can either be picked, or created via webcam). So far it allows the user to pick the media file or create one but I'm not sure how to attach that created file to the actual file button so it can be posted.

```
    function sendMail(){
    var blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url; 
    document.getElementById("media").appendChild(a);  
    }
```

This is what I'm trying but doesn't seem to be working. ('media' is the id of my file button I want to attach the file to).